# Using AndroidStudio, customize UI, buttons, callback to switch cameras... Any advice is very welcome

Tags: android

I'm really a newbie here. Using AndroidStudio,  Is there a way to customize UI, implement UI? e.g : buttons, callback to switch cameras... etc I've been looking for resources & still computing google results. Any advice is very welcome.

I've been looking for resources & still computing google results.

Comment: I've voted to close this as your question is quite unclear (IMO). "a way to customize UI, implement UI?" ? "callback to switch cameras... etc" ? What? Read this and try again: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.